# How to create new column in power bi using given string match condition in first column and get value from another column, make new column?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

My table is as follow

```
Col1 Col2

11_A    9
12_B    8
13_C    7
14_A    6
15_A    4
```

The table we need after the query

```
Col1  Col2  Col3

11_A    0   9
12_B    8   0
13_C    7   0
14_A    0   6
15_A    0   4
```

My query is

```
Col3 = 
LEFT( 'Table'[Col2], 
     SEARCH("A", 'Table'[Col1], 0, 
         LEN('Table'[Col1])
     )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the query designer `Add Column > Custom Column` and use the following expression:

[image]

[image]

**Update**

You need two expressions (two new columns) for this:

One is:

```
'Your Column3
=if Text.Contains([Col1], "A") = true then [Col2] else 0
```

And the second:

```
'Your Column2
=if Text.Contains([Col1], "A") = false then [Col2] else 0
```

Comment: For me it throwing an error something like given below ```The syntax for 'Text' is incorrect. (DAX(if Text.Contains([Col1],"A") = true then Text.Range([Col1],1,1) else 0))```, i'm using windows application.

Comment: This is M not DAX. You have to go to `Edit Queries > Add Column > Custom Column`

Comment: I'm getting Col3 is 1,0,3,0,5 that means Col1 values, not Col2 value, what we expected. Can you recheck the query, please.

Comment: I'm changed value due to understanding, sorry if you feel bad.

Comment: `If Text.Contain([Col1], "A") = ture then [Col2] else 0` Like this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this, 
Another easy way I like to do this with no-coding is to use Conditional Columns:

- In PBI select Power Query Editor
- Select your table on the edge of the screen
- Select Add Column tab
- Select Conditional Columns...
- Name your column
- Enter your condition as in the picture
- You can add several conditions if you like
- Don't forget to format your column to numeric if needed.

see picture

[Adding columns using Conditional Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfKv6.jpg)